# How to email invoice to customer who direct creditcard payment through PayPal?

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PayPal API to make direct payment with payment `method="creadit_card"`.

I need to send email of invoice to customer. Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide more information, describe your current approach and what is the show stopper problem.

Comment: I have rest API of paypal and my requirement is that:
- I have plan based application. In that i want to use paypal for get payment from client.
- So, I get take information from client through my website page and pass it to direct credit card method of PayPal rest API.
- Now i want to send the invoice to client for their transection.

Comment: Please guide what i can do or change for the this problem